# What to do with this dlib wheel compiling error

Tags: python, c++, cmake, dlib

I have struggled for weeks now trying to install dlib.
After watching many videos and reading a stack overflow, I feel like I did something wrong.

- OS: Windows 10
- Python: 3.8.2 amd_64

*Note, I ***did*** install cmake with the 64 and later 32 bit versions from the cmake website, but to no avail. I tried the VS method, (didn't work). I installed the cmake library via `pip install cmake` without any errors. I find that strange.
I tried everything, but it keeps throwing errors at me, for example earlier it said that my 32 bit Python was incompatible with the 64 bit cmake; then I installed 64 bit Python, same error; tried a 32 bit cmake, same error; then tried to find a wheel for my system (I didn't find one); tried to build my own... and here's where it gets strange.

Could anyone please help me understand what this message is trying to say, better yet, could someone help me make it work, better yet, help me with my issue.

I suspect my PATH may have something to do with it?

```
C:\Users\Markian\Downloads\dlib-19.9.0.tar\dist\dlib-19.9.0\dlib-19.9.0>python -m setup.py build
```

```
running build
running build_py
package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
running build_ext
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Markian\Downloads\dlib-19.9.0.tar\dist\dlib-19.9.0\dlib-19.9.0\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Markian\Down
loads\dlib-19.9.0.tar\dist\dlib-19.9.0\dlib-19.9.0\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Markian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe -DCMAK
E_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Markian\Downloads\dlib-19.9.0.tar\dist\dlib-19.9.0\dlib-19.9.0\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -A x64'
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
  contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
  code such as

    project(ProjectName)

  near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().

  CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
  line.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Markian/Downloads/dlib-19.9.0.tar/dist/dlib-19.9.0/dlib-19.9.0/build/temp.win-amd64-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Markian/Downloads/dlib-19.9.0.tar/dist/dlib-19.9.0/dlib-19.9.0/build/temp.win-amd64-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Markian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\Markian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\Markian\Downloads\dlib-19.9.0.tar\dist\dlib-19.9.0\dlib-19.9.0\setup.py", line 204, in <module>
    setup(
  File "C:\Users\Markian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Markian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Markian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Markian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Markian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\Markian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Markian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Markian\Downloads\dlib-19.9.0.tar\dist\dlib-19.9.0\dlib-19.9.0\setup.py", line 119, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\Markian\Downloads\dlib-19.9.0.tar\dist\dlib-19.9.0\dlib-19.9.0\setup.py", line 153, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
  File "C:\Users\Markian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Markian\\Downloads\\dlib-19.9.0.tar\\dist\\dlib-19.9.0\\dlib-19.9.0\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTP
UT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Markian\\Downloads\\dlib-19.9.0.tar\\dist\\dlib-19.9.0\\dlib-19.9.0\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\Markian\\AppData
\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Markian\\Downloads\\dlib-19.9.0.tar\\dist\\dlib-19.9.0\\dlib-19.9
.0\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I have no experience with subprocess.

Could anyone maybe point me towards a cp38 amd64 windows wheel for dlib?

Comment: Do you have a C/C++ compiler installed? From your error listing it looks like CMake is not able to find one.

Comment: If `python 3.8` isn't a strict requirement, then you could try using Anaconda with `python 3.7` or 3.6 environment.Install dlib with conda, `conda install -c conda-forge dlib`.